# Check current and previous checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am quite new to jquery and javascript to be honest and I am having trouble with checkboxes.

This works as #checkAll is a checkbox used for checking all the other checkboxes with class "check":

```
function test() {
if($("#checkAll").prop('checked')) {
    $(".check").prop('checked', true);
} else {
    $(".check").prop('checked', false);
}
}
```

However, I want it to work when I select any checkbox.  So I tried putting the function to all checkboxes as a click event, just using onclick="test()".

I think the problem is that I am trying to use $(this) but I must be using it wrongly, what I have is:

```
function test() {
if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(".check").prop("checked", true);
} else {
    $(".check").prop("checked", false);
}
}
```

"$(this)" also has the class "check", so maybe it's to do with that.

Ultimately I want to check one box and it check all previous checkboxes, not ones that come afterwards.  I think if I get my head around why this isn't working then I should be able to figure that out.  I'm not lazy, just learning!!

I have searched for an answer but cannot find one.  I'm hoping someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `onclick="test()"`, you call `test()` in the global context, so `this` is going to be set to `window`, not your DOM element. You can solve this in a couple ways.

You could [D4V1D's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329358/3187556), passing a parameter.

You could also use `test.call(this)`, to manually force the context to be the DOM element.

You could also attach the event handlers via jQuery instead of as attributes:

```
$(".check").click(test);
```

jQuery will automatically call the callback with the correct context.

BTW, i recommend you look at [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) for what you want to do next.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `this` as a parameter of your function as such:

```
onclick="test(this);"
```

And use it in your function like so:

```
function test(that) {
    if($(that).prop('checked')) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
```

Here's some jQuery to check all previous checkboxes:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).prevAll().prop("checked", true);
});
```